# How to register permanent spark udf?

Tags: apache-spark, view, user-defined-functions, permanent

I'd like to use my udf in other sessions or in a view so is there any way to register permanent Spark UDF written in Python or scala?

Answer (score 3):

you can't. Spark doesn't have a "server" it talks with a resource manager (Yarn/Kubernetes/Mesos) and deploys itself anew with each job. You either need to have the code as part of the package you submit or in the prepackage in  jar/zip file which you include in the job. In both cases you need to register the udfs.

Comment: Thanks. Need to write it in Java Hive UDF and register

Comment: Is not this terribly annoying? In Cobol you can have a copy book include. Is there something like that in Scala? They cannot be called dynamically in anyway? So, what if the code vase of the UDFs changes?